# XamDataGrid RowDataBound similar event

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Is there any event on the XamDatagrid control that allows me to check when every row is bound to the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest event to what you are looking for is the [InitializeRecord](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~InitializeRecord_EV.html) Event.